# R set.seed reproduce by another user on another computer

Tags: r, seed

I've been working with the set.seed function. Here is a super simple example from the r documentation.

```
> set.seed(5)
> rnorm(5)
[1] -0.84085548  1.38435934 -1.25549186  0.07014277  1.71144087
> set.seed(5)
> rnorm(5)
[1] -0.84085548  1.38435934 -1.25549186  0.07014277  1.71144087
```

I have R Version 1.3.1093

Now, I tried these lines in my own RStudio and got the same numbers. All good.

But my question is: If I send code to another person on another machine that involves set.seed, am I guaranteed that this other user will get the same 5 numbers? What are the things that I need to consider in order to know that this is true? As long as they have the same version of R that I used, this is guaranteed? I would like to know if there is a 'test' that I could use to ensure that someone (for example, a boss) would get the exact same data as long as he/she has the same version of R.

Comment: I not sure about the answer, but I just want to add that I tested with R 4.0.3 and 3.6.3 and got the same values.

Comment: Oh thanks that’s super helpful to know

Comment: There is no 'R 1.3.1093'. That is your RStudio version and it is *independent* of the R installation you have.

Comment: thanks I typed "version" into the console and this is what I get. Apparently I have 3.6.1
This nickname thing is super weird 
version.string R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
nickname       Action of the Toes

Comment: I just got the same results on Ubuntu with 4.2.2, and on Mac with 4.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the random number generation depends on the RNG kind used. R uses Mersenne-Twister as the default RNG changing this will change the result not only in different platforms but even on the same computer. For example try doing

```
RNGkind('Wich')
set.seed(5)
rnorm(5)
```

You will note that the results you obtain are quite different.

Note that depending on the generator chosen, you will get different results, even on the same computer. Run `RNGkind('default')` to go back to the default generator.

Notice that numbers generated by a computer are technically not random, but rather pseudo - random. Probably it is possible to generate the exact numbers using the same generator on a different platform/ language. (Still not quite sure about this- Hopefully it will be possible).